# How can I get an info from third table in SQL

Tags: sql, select

I need an info from a table which I can't get directly. So in one table I have people's names in second names of categories and third is the middle one(which is between them) cause relation is many-many. Now I need info which people are in category 'A' for example. I tried like this, but it is not working.

```
select 
   p.name,p.surname  
from people p, category c, category_people cp 
where 
p.ID=cp.fk_ID_people and c.name='a';
```

From that I get list of all people, which is incorrect.
Please help. I also think that my logic is not working right.
Thank you.

Comment: How the schema look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra condition, since it seems like the `category_people` is the table making the many-to-many connection possible.

So that table probably has a `fk_ID_people` and a `fk_ID_category` field and you would need to update your query to:

```
select 
   p.name,p.surname  
from people p, category c, category_people cp 
where 
      p.ID=cp.fk_ID_people 
  and c.ID = cp.fk_ID_category
  and c.name='a';
```

Answer (score 0):

For the best practices you should always `join` instead of using `where` condition.

```
select 
   p.name,
   p.surname  
from people p

join category_people cp
on p.ID = cp.fk_ID_people 

join category c
on c.ID = cp.fk_ID_category

where 
    c.name='a';
```